# Matrix equivalence via orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. We say they are equivalent if there are $P,Q$ invertible such that $A=QBP$ (note this is weaker than similarity). Every matrix is equivalent to a diagonal matrix using row and column operations.

My question is - when is $A$ equivalent to a diagonal matrix via orthogonal matrices? That is, for which $A$ there are a diagonal $D$ and orthogonal $P,Q$ such that $A=PDQ$?

$A$  is *orthogonally diagonizable* iff it is self adjoint, but this seems to be strictly stronger (it means there $A=P^{T}DP$ for an orthogonal $P$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always. That's because every real/complex square matrix admits a [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).